# Create content organizer rules for all parent Document content type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created content organizer rule for my custom content type which inherited by Document content type. Also i have assign my custom router.

But when i am submitting any document then its not routed. When i have created rule for my content type then this document is routed perfectly.

In my project i am having 50 odd number of content types. Creating rules for all is very tedious job. Is there any alternative way to create content organizer rules for all parent Document content type and work for my child content types.....?

Comment: You can have a look at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/content-organizer-in-a-records-management-scenario-for-multiple-content-types